# Android Studio multiple dex files defined

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

I've got 2 jar libraries I'm including that both have a copy of gson.jar and because of this when I try to run my project I get an exception saying 
    UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION Multiple Dex Files defined.  I've found several sources saying to just remove one of the libraries however I can't because I need other items included in both jars. Is there a way to keep both jars in the project and still get it to run

Comment: You need to use `exclude module:` in `build.gradle`

Comment: How do I find out which module to exclude?  I've tried running ./gradle dependencies in my terminal but it says it's been deprecated. I also tried adding exclude module: 'gson-2.3.jar' but it's still in their when I build the project

Answer (score 1):

try deleting the classes of the folder  bin\dexedLibs of your project maybe this is the place where is generated a copy of the jar

Comment: Thank u Scott that did solve my problem to add exclude module. Thank u so much for that link.  Instead of exclude module:'gson-2.3.jar' I used exclude module: 'gson'

Comment: Thank you, you inspired me to go to: MyProject folder -> build -> intermediate -> dex-cache -> cache.xml opened this and deleted items of support-v4.jar manually. Then cleaned the project and ran it and it worked :) Thank u